# Unique row ID with reuse

Tags: postgresql

I would like to generate 32 bit unique integer id for each row.

```
create table my_table (
    uid serial primary key,
    some_text text
);
```

The number of rows at any time will not exceed 2147483647 (limit of 32 bit signed int), but rows can be deleted and new ones inserted. This may lead to the sequence reaching its end. Therefore I would like to reuse ids of deleted rows. What is the best way to do it?

Comment: I'd say the "best" way would be to simply define the column as bigint and forget about it. Depending on the rate of new inserts, an `integer` might be good enough as well. If you consume one sequence value **per second**, 24/7 it would still take 68 years to get a duplicate value

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: Sorry, bigint is not allowed by the requirements. In my case int overflow is a distinct possibility within reasonable time.

Comment: So at which rate are you consuming the sequence values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

***Getting up on my soapbox.***
Let's be frank: there is no best way to do this, there is not even 'sort-of good' method. Maybe a least bad method? Well 2 possibilities:

1. Create a table 'reusable_unique_ids'. Then when you get the inevitable overflow select (and delete) a value from it. Good luck coordinating that.
2. There is actually nothing requiring unsigned values for a sequence generator. So create one that automatically wraps to large negative values on the inevitable overflow.

Let's investigate #2.

```
create sequence wrap_around_id_generator
     increment by 1
     minvalue -2147483646  
     maxvalue  2147483646   
     start     1  
     cycle  
;

create table my_table (
    uid integer default nextval('wrap_around_id_generator') primary key
  , some_text text
);
```

Now when negative id start showing up you have time to prepare for correcting the imposed limit of your id.  
  
Please raise the issue of "bigint is not allowed by the requirements" and get it changed especially since integer overflow is expected. The **best** method is change that requirement, it is the only reasonable solution given the expectation. And, at least IMHO it is your job to do so, don't hide behind "that is the requirement". *Poor requirements produce poor systems. **Always***  
OK, getting off the soapbox.

Comment: 32 bit requirements comes from RAM limit (not DB storage). I will go with reusable ids  table and run it as a separate service - solves coordination problem.